# How do fit a webview based on the device screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

My webviews are used with fragments. Fragments work nicely but the only one thing left is to make them fit exacly based on device screen. If device screen is smaller, webview itself fits based on that screen. If device is larger, webview itself fits based on that screen. How to make it like that?

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

These two didn't work like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Once try to use along :

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Can I manually setUseWideViewPort to some kind of size? Like, how far can it go or how close can it get? Because if I just use it normally, it doesn't fit all contents to a screen. Only 2 contents are on screen and others are further away to right side. I have to use just swipe to right to see other contents which I want to avoid.

Comment: @Kristen :  contents, which aren't displaying in fit to screen you can control them data side. means if you use HTML data then control it towards HTML.